# IdentityServer4 use sql server with .net core 3

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to configure IdentityServer4 in a .Net Core 3 project.

My ConfigureServices-Method looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"*redacted*", "*redacted*"))
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.GetUsers().ToList())
                .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(...))
```

Unfortunately, the `builder.UseSqlServer(...)` which used to work in earlier versions is not available anymore.

What is the correct way to configure IdentityServer4 to use an SQL Server nowadays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package?

Comment: Yes the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package is installed (with the newest version 3.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseSqlServer(...);
})
```